# Android sensors - which to use for controlling mouse cursor/crosshair?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, gyroscope

What I'm thinking of is using my phone as a mouse cursor, or more specifically the gun crosshair in a game.

I want to attach my phone to a toy gun/cardboard gun and send the sensor values over WiFi/Bluetooth to my PC. When I tilt or move the gun up/down, the crosshair moves up/down. When I rotate or move the gun left/right, the crosshair moves left/right. I do not want to recognize side-to-side tilt.

If you imagine the phone lying flat on a table with the screen facing the ceiling, then head/bottom tilt is called *pitch*, side-to-side tilt is *roll*, and spinning the phone around in a circle is *yaw*?

---

1) If that's correct, then do I only want to recognize x/y acceleration and pitch/yaw rotation?

2) Out of

- TYPE_ACCELEROMETER
- TYPE_GYROSCOPE
- TYPE_GRAVITY
- TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION
- TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD
- TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR

which am I looking for?

3) There's conflicting information on filtering out drift and noise. Comments tell you to use a moving average, a low-pass filter, a high-pass filter, a complementary filter, a Kalman filter, etc. I've also read some sources that say the phone code already has a filter.